# Проблема с построением дерева элемента HTML

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

необходимо вытащить запрос на получение новых отзывов [отсюда](https://www.spr.ru/otzyvy/sm-klinika-1111439.html) и преобразовать к HTML-дереву

Сначала был выбран регуляркой блок между " "

```
url_page = "https://www.spr.ru/js/zzz_next.php?id_top=11&id_firm=1111439&view11=60&all11=71&rnd=0.6922828585538536"
    r = requests.request("GET", url_page, proxies=proxy[0], auth=proxy[1]).content

    #Разбор вручную
    r_text = re.search(r'".*"', str(r)).group(0)
    #Избавились от кавычек
    r_text = r_text.replace('"', '')
```

Теперь мне нужно построить дерево для парсинга, beautiful soup 4 не справляется (и lxml и html.parser)

Попробовал изменить кодировки в при конвертировании регулярки, наподобии

```
r_text = re.search(r'".*"', str(r, "utf-8")).group(0)
```

Выкидывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Project/Parsers_site/spr_ru.py", line 159, in <module>
    spr_ru("https://www.spr.ru/otzyvy/sm-klinika-1111439.html")
  File "D:/Project/Parsers_site/spr_ru.py", line 25, in spr_ru
    r_text = re.search(r'".*"', str(r, "utf-8")).group(0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 249: invalid continuation byte
```

Есть еще идеи? Может я в кодировке самой ошибся?

Comment: Сервер в своём ответе чётко указывает кодировку windows-1251

Comment: @andreymal да, только если я указал эту кодировку, то Bs4 все равно не может по нему построить дерево, получается &lt;div style=\"margin-bottom:7px;\"&gt;&lt;a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"//www.spr.ru/forum_vyvod.php?id_tema=3556012\" class=\"zagolovok\" title=\"Дата отзыва: 2016-04-03. Автор: Галина\"

Comment: Он его и не построит никогда, потому что это не html, а javascript

Comment: @andreymal с чего вы взяли, что этот код javascript? Если, я вручную в текстовом редакторе по таблице изменю эти коды на элементы, то вполне будет структура html, правда без первоначальных элементов Html head и body, но это обработает Html.parser

Comment: Вы сами-то открывали свою ссылку? Там с первых строк начинается javascript-код: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8IUm.png — а дальше идёт экранированная js-строка, которую Bs4 парсить просто так не умеет

Comment: @andreymal мы эту часть обрезали регулярным выражением, разве нет?

Comment: Возможно, но в итоге вы всё равно получили кусок экранированной js-строки, парсить которую Bs4 всё равно не умеет. Более того, вы её окончательно сломали, удалив все кавычки, которые являются важной частью синтаксиса html. В то же время обратные слэши \ являющиеся частью синтаксиса javascript, вы не удалили

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать `r_text = json.loads(re.search(r'".*"', str(r)).group(0))` — оно совершенно не обязано работать, потому что json это не javascript, но в отдельных частных случаях вроде вашего может и прокатить

Comment: json не работает, допустим я не буду заменять кавычки, а просто отсеку первый элемент и с последний элемент

Comment: Обратные слэши \ всё равно оставили. И всё равно не факт, что это будет работать, потому что полноценно обработать с javascript сможет, очевидно, только javascript-движок

Comment: @andreymal \ к сожалению не знаю как можно удалить, replace не работает

Comment: `r_text.replace('\\', '')` отлично работает

Comment: @andreymal заменил спецсимволы &lt; &gt; &quot;, обработал bs4 и сработало, нашелся элемент

Answer (score 0):

Получилось с костылями, но лучше так, чем использовать Selenium.

```
    r_text = re.search(r'".*"', str(r, "windows-1251")).group(0)
    r_text = r_text[1:-1]
    r_text = r_text.replace('\\', '')
    r_text = r_text.replace('&lt;', '<')
    r_text = r_text.replace('&gt;', '>')
    r_text = r_text.replace('&quot;', '"')
    html = ph.get_html(r_text, 'lxml')
    a = html.select_one("a.zagolovok")
    print(a.text)
```

Comment: Лучше использовать Selenium, чем так))

Comment: @andreymal ну я бы не сказал, потребление ОЗУ, нагрузка на CPU. А больше 10 потоков будет грузить мой ноутбук под 100%, а тут всего лишь делать запросы request